# clipPath не выполняется

Tags: svg

```html
<svg width='400' height='400' style='border: 1px solid black'>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="myclipPath">
         <polygon points="20,30 40,10 60,30" fill='red'/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <circle clip-path="url(#myclipPath)" r="100" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="green"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обтравка ни чего не вырезает **потому что за пределами круга**:

*Равно как и здесь: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/KKpgLYZ я обвёл девочку по контуру её тела так и сработал clip-path и кстати обводил руками то есть ручная работа*

Что бы вырезать надо полигон поставить точнее **нарисовать на круге**

```html
<svg width='400' height='400' style='border: 1px solid black'>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="myclipPath">
         <polygon points="20,30 40,10 60,30" fill='red'/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  
  <circle  r="100" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="green"/>
  <polygon points="20,30 40,10 60,30" fill='red'/>
</svg>
```

В этом примере обтравка вырезает, изменил только координаты круга

```html
<svg width='400' height='400' style='border: 1px solid black'>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="myclipPath">
         <polygon points="20,30 40,10 60,30" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  
  <circle r="100" cx="0%" cy="0%" fill="green" clip-path="url(#myclipPath)"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Функцию `clipPath` может выполнять маска с определенными настройками.
 Это более мощный инструмент, позволяющий получить дополнительные возможности.

При окраске в белый цвет маска работает, как `clipPath`, обрезая всё остальное и показывая только то, что входит в `polygon`, прописанный в маске.

`<mask id="myMask" fill="white">`

*В ответе ниже за основу взят код @MaximLensky*

```html
<svg width='400' height='400' style='border: 1px solid black'>
  <defs>
    <mask id="myMask" fill="white">
         <polygon points="20,30 40,10 60,30" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  
  <circle r="100" cx="0%" cy="0%" fill="green" mask="url(#myMask)" />
</svg>
```

Если добавить в маске окраску фона,  отличающуюся от белого цвета, то можно получить полупрозрачный фон вокруг треугольника:

```
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
```

```html
<svg width='400' height='400' style='border: 1px solid black'>
  <defs>
    <mask id="myMask" > 
      <rect fill="red" widht="100%" height="100%"  />
         <polygon fill="white" points="20,30 40,10 60,30" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  
  <circle r="100" cx="0%" cy="0%" fill="green" mask="url(#myMask)" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Уберите символ `#`:

```html
<svg width='400' height='400' style='border: 1px solid black'>
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="myclipPath">
            <polygon points="20,30 40,10 60,30" fill='red'/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <circle clip-path="url(myclipPath)" r="100" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="green"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: символ` #` нельзя убирать. В вашем ответе без него `clip-path` не работает. Просто выводится зелёный круг.  Для проверки этого,  уберите совсем `clip-path="url(myclipPath)"` результат будет тот же. Опять просто зелёный круг